# TSQL Row Number split by reference and date

Tags: t-sql, row

Using a single table with a reference and date column example below, how could I produce the out below to split the row number. The same reference on the same day should show as the same row number.

example below;

```
MAINFRAJOB  SyncDate    Row Number
7861    02/10/2019  1
7861    02/10/2019  1
7861    03/10/2019  2
1045679 25/09/2019  1
10233649    03/10/2019  1
10233652    04/10/2019  1
10233652    04/10/2019  1
10233652    06/10/2019  2
123456789   02/10/2019  1
123456789   02/10/2019  1
123456789   03/10/2019  2
123456789   04/10/2019  3
```

I have tried this but it is not producing the correct results;

```
ROW_NUMBER()over(partition by cast(ard.SyncDate as date), ard.actionref order by cast(ard.SyncDate as date) desc) AS 'RowNo'
```

Thanks for any guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are really looking for `Dense_Rank()` as BarneyL mentioned, but you also want to partition by `MAINFRAJOB`

**Example**

```
Select *
      ,Row_Number = DENSE_RANK() over (Partition By [MAINFRAJOB] Order by [SyncDate])
 From YourTable
```

Returns

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try DENSE_RANK instead, you also need to remove the date from the partition otherwise it resets to 1 each date change:

```
DENSE_RANK()over(partition by cast(ard.SyncDate as date), ard.actionref order by cast(ard.SyncDate as date) desc) AS 'RowNo'
```